# How to change default compression mode in mariaDB Columnstore?

Tags: mariadb, configuration, columnstore

In mariaDB there is a way to disable columnstore compression in session level (and set the disable flag in each session). Is there any way to change the default compression mode?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, but I don't want to set the parameter at the session level. I wish to change the default... I have to revise my question...

Comment: A large part of the beauty of ColumnStore is its compression.  What do you hope to gain by changing the default?

Comment: I want to check if this will improve the insert speed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of `INSERT` in Columnstore, but I would suspect the following:

- Inserting one row is quite costly.
- The code will consider the tradeoffs when adding more data row-by-row
- Probably:  Batch inserting (especially of 64K or more rows) is better optimized.

So...  How fast are you inserting rows?  Are they being inserted in clumps?  What I might do is to gather rows until

- I have collected X rows, OR
- Y minutes have passed

After whichever of those happens, then I would do a batch insert.

X might be 10K; Y might be 20 minutes.  But those depend on the desired performance characteristics of the application.

(For InnoDB, I recommend batches of 100-1000 or 1MB of gathered Insert text.  This runs about 10 times as fast as one-row-at-a time.)

Comment: I am trying to do a speed test between ColumnStore and InnoDB . I need to find a solution that loads data, analyze it and finally delete it. I am using streamsets and check what each solution can offer.

Comment: This is really interesting info, and I am trying to apply it for my tests.

Comment: @ssavva05 - It seems useless to have a table that is not `SELECTed`.  And that is where ColumnStore will (for some queries) run much faster than InnoDB.